# How to change height of Section class pt 100 in twitter bootsrap

Tags: css

I want to change height of section class pt 100 without changing 
height of section bellow.

I'm using
Polo - Responsive Multi-Purpose HTML5 Template

http://www.inspirothemes.com/polo-v4/home-corporate-v5.html

This is for my website.

Screenshot of my problem:
https://prnt.sc/mknrpm

It's important for me to minimize empty spaces like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'empty space' you want to minimize is due to `padding-bottom` value of all sections in your theme.
Setting `padding-bottom: 0;` to that p-y-100 section will solve your problem > 
[here a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAsfr.png).

This not the best solution because this value will be attributed to all items with `class="p-y-100"`. Try to select in a more specific way that section and then set `padding-bottom: 0;`